# Performance of SQL Server on Amazon EC2?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

Does anyone have performance stories to share about running SQL Server 2008 on Amazon EC2 instances? We are performing some tests, and not unexpectedly see some disk IO performance issues. Specifically, avg disk queues backing up as much as 6,500 deep. where on similar physical hardware, the queues never go above 20.

The test instance only uses 2 disk volumes, 1 for OS, 1 for data, with separate data and index filespaces. Would additional EBS disk volumes reduce some of the IO bottlenecks, or does EBS eliminate the benefit we would see with separate physical volumes for data, index, and logs?

Comment: It also depends on the instance type, the smaller instances are allocated lower bandwidth I/O channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RAID-0 with several EBS volumes will increase performance, but in the end disk I/O is shared on AWS, which is why you will see better speeds on a dedicated machine.

Comment: I've the same requirement as that of OP here, but for *PostgreSQL* database.  `Using RAID-0 with several EBS volumes will increase performance` -- can you share on how to setup one?